# How do you fill a text field in an edit form in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jqgrid

I'm new to javascript. I've created an editable table using jqGrid. It opens a form to add a new entry, and I have added a button which automatically fills in some of the text boxes in the form.

So by clicking the button, it calls the functions below.
    $('#tr_Field',form).val('Autofilled');

and

```
$('#tr_Field',form).attr('value','Autofilled');
```

Both seem to work (if i call the $('#tr_Field',form).val(); function it gives 'Autofilled').

However, it doesn't show this new value in the text box in the currently open form.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input field will have an id exactly how you have set it's name on `colModel`. For example, if you have a code like this: `colModel:[{name:'YOUR_INPUT_NAME', width:120, sortable:false, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}}]`, you can set it's text using: `$('#YOUR_INPUT_NAME').val('Autofilled');`. If you have trouble looking for an element id, you can press F12 and pass the mouse over the element, so that you'll see it's properties